# Getting Item Description using Forge Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am using the Forge Data Management API to search for documents within a BIM 360 Docs folder/subfolder.
The used endpoint is https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search

the received results does not contain "Description" Attribute.

what I need is:
1- Ability to search using the Description attribute as filtering criteria.
2- Show the Description attribute in the result.

Comment: As I know, either GET:Folder Contents or Search has not exposed [Description] field with the item. I am checking with engineer team if they have any news or tricks.

Comment: My sincerer apology for the late response! I finally logged two wishes with the suggestions of engineer team:  FDM-3124 expose [Description] with GET :Folder Contents   FDM-3125: Folder Search can provide filter with [Description]  your patience is appreciated.